# How to Logically Break Down a System for Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I am working on a Java program that takes in information on various locations (could be a continent, country, city or point of interest) and creates a database that can be searched through.  Currently I have a Location object class that has the variables for name, population, area and then Continent, Country, City and POI objects that extend the Location class.  I thought that this would be a viable structure for the program, however POI objects do not have a Continent associated with it or population.

I have a couple questions about my design:

1) Is the Location class necessary (Does it improve the implementation?

2) If it is, then should the class itself or the methods be abstract?

3) If it isn't could you point me in a good direction of a logical breakdown of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the take away from this question should be a survey of general interface hierarchy design guidelines. In java, it's typical to design an interface hierarchy instead of a concrete (or abstract) class hierarchy. That's because java does not support mixins (until java 8 that is). I'll go ahead and distill a few practices I have found useful in big production systems.

First of all, imagine what your API will look like in terms of interfaces. For example given something like:

```
interface Location{ ... }
interface City extends Location{ ... }
// etc.
```

write code against these interfaces. For example you might want to write code like this:

```
City city = ... // create a city instance
city.getName();
city.getPopulation(); // possibly city specific
city.getCoordinates();
city.getState(); // most likely city specific!
```

But maybe having a `Location.getPopulation()` doesn't make sense: imagine what that means if it's a location in the middle of the Pacific Ocean! Maybe even `getName()` could belong to a different object:

```
interface NamedLocation extends Location{ 
  String getName();
}
```

and thus:

```
interface City extends NamedLocation{ ... }
```

If a method does not make sense at some level of the hierarchy, don't put it there. If you need more specific sub/super-types, add new interfaces.

A city is a named location. A named location is a location. Always respect the "is-a" principle. A city **has** boroughs, it **is not** just a collection of boroughs, so you wouldn't write:

```
interface Borough extends NamedLocation{ ... }
interface City extends Collection<Borough>{ ... } // BAD!
```

but:

```
interface Borough extends NamedLocation{ ... }
interface City extends NamedLocation{ 
  ... 
  // the city is much more than a collection of boroughs,
  // but it HAS them
  Collection<Borough> getBoroughs();
}
```

Another example could be:

```
interface Region extends Location{
  Boundaries getBoundaries();
}
```

A region, i.e., a state, continent, ocean, etc. might be represented as a location with boundaries. The boundaries might be represented in many ways, e.g., list of coordinates on a map. That's why I didn't define the `getBoundaries()` method as returning a `Collection<Boundary>` (what's that even mean?). The coordinates of a region might be not well defined, e.g., what are the coordinates of Australia? The coordinates of the boundaries might be though. The rule of thumb for the above is the "is-a" vs "contains" rule: a `Region` contains `Boundaries` it is **not** `Boundaries`.

The cool thing is that you can then do something like:

```
interface State extends Region, NamedLocation{ ... }
```

That is you can mix many interfaces together if it makes sense.

Such a design approach can be overwhelming at first but you can start small and add more intermediate classes later. The end result will be very flexible. The main principle is that each concept can be represented with a new layer (a new interface) although it doesn't have to if you determine it's overkill.

The implementation is a different story in the sense that you could have a hierarchy for locations on Earth and one for location on the Moon. That's where the power lies: all your methods written against interfaces will work both on Earth and the Moon!

As an example of an interface hierarchy that defines an API look at the JDBC specification or at more modern libraries such as Spring or my personal favorite [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained). For example in JDBC you create a `DataSource` and then take it from there:

```
DataSource ds = ... // create a driver specific datasource
Connection con = ds.getConnection(); // get a connection
PreparedStatement pstmt;
try {
  pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE COFFEES " +
    "SET PRICE = ? " +
    "WHERE COF_NAME = ?");
  pstmt.setFloat(1, price);
  pstmt.setString(2, cofName);
  pstmt.executeUpdate();
  pstmt.close();
} finally {
  if (con != null) con.close();
}
```

All the objects above, `DataSource`, `Connection` and `PreparedStatement`, are JDBC interfaces. The power of the API lies in the fact that there is nothing driver specific to it so innumerable vendors can implement it for their own RDBMS.

I hope that helps! Have fun designing interface hierarchies!

Comment: To begin, very useful information, thank you for the response.  I will process this information and let you know if I have any questions and how my design ends up. PS I now realize when I said I would be creating a database it appears to the veteran programmer I meant something more than a way to store multiple collections of objects.  I was wondering if I should store all the Continent, Country, City and POI objects in a single collection, or have each Continent object have a Collection<Country>, each Country have a Collection<City> for all the cities it contains?

Comment: After reading through it seems the latter that I suggested at the end of my comment fits your approach?

Comment: You could do it that way or you could separate the two concepts. If you are familiar with databases your city table would have a foreign key to a country, so you can map each country to a list of cities. In your object model you can make this explicit, i.e., have country contain a collection of cities, or implicit, i.e., have a separate service return the collection of cities given the country. If you were to use JPA and Hibernate there would be different technical implications for either approaches (lazy fetching and such).

Answer (score 0):

You have defined an abstract entity that you call "Location", which can be a continent, a country, a city or a POI.

The simplest way to model this is to create an interface Location, and 4 classes that implement this interface: Continent, Country, City and PointOfInterest.

For the fields you mention, you should think to which of these class(es) they apply. Population and area (could) apply to Continent, Country and City, so you could add them to all three. But to avoid duplication, you could introduce an abstract super class for these 3 (e.g. Area), and put these fields there. But then, this makes Continent, Country and City empty; they don't have any fields themselves. This means they are identical, and should not be implemented in three separate classes. You should come up with more properties for each of the classes to distinguish themselves.

The PointOfInterest is different from Continent, Country and City, as it typically won't have the properties you mention. It is sufficient to only implement the Location interface. Again, you should come up with properties to make it useful.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense.  The greater issue I am running into is the fact that I am creating a database that will need to be sorted and searched through, however I am unsure how to store the collection of Continents, Countries, Cities etc.  Should I create a LinkedHashMap<String countryName, Country country> inside the Continent class and implement the methods to add and remove countries from the list inside the Continent class as well?  I would do this for each Continent with countryList, Country with cityList, Country with poiList.  Note that this program will implement ActionListener.

Comment: Do you mean that you will store them in a database (e.g. Oracle)? Then you don't necessarily need to keep a collection of the objects yourself. You can query the database for the continents, countries, etc you need.

Comment: I now realize that a database was the improper description.  I am curious about what I posted on Giovanni's answer. " I now realize when I said I would be creating a database it appears to the veteran programmer I meant something more than a way to store multiple collections of objects. I was wondering if I should store all the Continent, Country, City and POI objects in a single collection, or have each Continent object have a Collection<Country>, each Country have a Collection<City> for all the cities it contains?"

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you could implement something like this. Anyways, this is how I would structure it if it was me:

Location is pretty abstract, so I'd make that the `abstract` base class for each object.

Each class has its own interface:

`IContinent`
`ICountry`
`ICity`
`IPointOfInterest`

with their own members/methods, depending on what you see fit for each interface. For instance, `population` would go in `ICity`, `ICountry`, and `IContinent` but not in `IPointOfInterest`

So each class line would like something like this:

```
abstract class Location {
    protected String id;
}


class Continent extends Location implements IContinent {
}

class Country extends Location implements ICountry, IContinent {
}

class City extends Location implements ICity, ICountry, IContinent {
}

class PointOfInterest extends Location implements IPointOfInterest, ICity, ICountry, IContinent {
}
```

Comment: Why would each class have an interface? What advantage does this add? Purely curious, not questioning if it is a proper implementation.

Comment: Having interfaces for each class defines what the class needs to implement. If things change in the interfaces, the classes will not compile. And the interfaces provide a separation between the objects - certain things will be in a `ICountry` interface that may not exist in `IPointOfInterest`. Also, another reason (not necessarily a benefit) to use interfaces is to define functionality when you don't care about the implementation. It's like a contract: "I don't care how you do it, but if you use this interface, you must provide me with whatever the interface defines"